# Adding a column - please improve my code

Tags: sql-server, date-format

Pretty new to SQL Server. I tried to find a way to easily add a new column to a table. It's just taking an existing date column and giving it a different format. The only way I could get it to work was to create a new table, then drop the old table, and rename the new table.. Very inefficient surely

```
Use [Manipulate MC BS]
select*,
 CONVERT(date,[Time_stamp], 103) AS [Date Fixed]
into [Website Interactions - Raw2]
from [Website Interactions - Raw]
drop table [Website Interactions - Raw]
Use [Manipulate MC BS]
Go
sp_RENAME 'Website Interactions - Raw2','Website Interactions - Raw'
Go
```

How can I do this without creating a new table?

Thanks!
Lucas

Comment: why you want to save TIMESTAMP as a string not a good practice at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just add a computed column.  These take up no additional storage space, but will allow you to see the result.  The function is "build-in" to the table, kind of like having a view within the table.  You can read about them [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

In your case, you would do:

```
ALTER TABLE
    ADD COLUMN [Date Fixed] AS CONVERT(date,[Time_stamp], 103);
```

This is very convenient.  If you add new rows or change the data in `[Time_stamp]`, the value of `[Date Fixed]` will automatically change.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
ALTER TABLE [Website Interactions - Raw]
ADD [Date Fixed] TIMESTAMP
```

(use whatever data type you need, I used TIMESTAMP as an example)

And then you could do something like:

```
UPDATE [Website Interactions - Raw]
SET [Date Fixed]=CONVERT(date,[Time_stamp], 103)
WHERE 1;
```

The last `WHERE 1` is not required if you're doing the update to all rows.
If you only need to update some, set a condition: `WHERE some_column=some_value;`

Yes, this is still 2 queries, but should be much more efficient than copying a table into another one, then dropping the original and renaming new into old...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to add, I used http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp<br/>
and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp<br/>
There are tons more examples there...

Answer (score 1):

Not a good practice to save datetime or date datatype as strings(Varchar, Char) datatype
but if you do want to do that you can do something like this.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ADD NewColumn VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT CONVERT(date,GETDATE(), 103)
```

Update the column.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET NewColumn = CONVERT(date,GETDATE(), 103)
```

**My Suggestion**

to store the data in DATE or DATETIME something like this

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ADD NewColumn DATE DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

And again you will need to update column for the existing records in your table.

Dropping Table and creating a new one may look an easier option. But if you have any Foreign keys or Permission on the table you may run into problems.